# How to ensure the interval between two requests reaching the server while using Lodash Throttle?

Tags: lodash, throttling

When using the throttle function in lodash, I encountered a situation where it is necessary to ensure a sufficient time interval between two network requests. Due to network latency, two requests spaced one second apart might simultaneously reach the server. I expect the second request to be initiated 1 second after the completion of the first request to ensure that the interval between their arrivals at the server is not less than 1 second. Is it possible to achieve this goal using the existing throttle function in lodash, or are there other recommended methods?

```js
export default () => {
  const sendRequest = () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 3000)) // 3 seconds
  const throttledRequest = throttle(
    () => {
      console.log(now(), 'Execute Request')
      sendRequest().then(() => console.log(now(), 'Obtain Results'))
    }, 10000, { leading: true, trailing: true } // 10 seconds
  )

  const triggerRequest = () => {
    console.log(now(), 'Trigger Action')
    throttledRequest()
  }

  return <button onClick={triggerRequest}>click</button>
}
```

> Assuming a double-click on the button at 00:00, the first request triggers immediately, and the first results are obtained at 00:03.
> Currently, the second request is sent at 00:10, and the second results are obtained at 00:13.
> The expectation is to send the second request at 00:13 and get the second results at 00:16. (After waiting for 10 seconds following the first response at 00:03)